# Error 500 in IIS

Tags: c#, angularjs, iis, asmx, http-error

I get Error 500 with web service when i try to connect externally to my server, if i try to connect with localhost, it works perfectly.

http://localhost/validuser.asmx/validarusuario (Work)

http://192.168.0.97/validuser.asmx/validarusuario (not work)

Its a call to a method of a c# webservice, if i put only the asmx, works in two urls, localhost and external.

Comment: error 500 means you have server error. It is impossible to tell what the error is without seeing this error. Please turn off custom errors in web.config and post error here. <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Check your IIS log. The sub type error could give you some clues.

This error is definitely in the application tier (most likely in your code but could be in parameter binding or other system level info).

Adding some break points might help. If you are using Visual Studio you can also click on the debug menu, click "Exceptions ...", and check Common Language Exceptions for the "Thrown" column.

Comment: Its a webapp with angularjs and $http.post, in the log of IIS i have nothing and the browser only send me the error 500.

Comment: @Bibliotec: Angular runs on the client side, so this is not (directly) generating the 500 level error. If you are really getting a 500 error using IIS you will be able to find a 500 error in your IIS log. Recommend adding angular to your tags above.

Comment: I add CORS in my IIS and now i get this error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404